# Expansion panel inside dynamic scroller (vue-virtual-scroller)

Tags: vue-component, vuetify.js, virtualscroll

I want to render a list of  components using the DynamicScroller in the vue-virtual-scroller package.

This is my template:

```
    <DynamicScroller :items="toDos" :min-item-size="190" class="scroller pr-3 fill-height">
        <template v-slot="{ item, index, active }">
            <DynamicScrollerItem :item="item" :active="active" :data-index="index">
                <ToDoItem :toDo="item" v-on:updateToDo="updateToDo" />
            </DynamicScrollerItem>
        </template>
    </DynamicScroller>
```

The 'ToDoItem' contains a vuetify expansion panel.

When the expansion button of a 'ToDoItem' is clicked, panel of a random 'ToDoItem' is expanded.

I tried adding the ":key" attribute, But it did not work.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Struggling with the same issue, there is a size-dependencies prop exists on a DynamicScrollerItem. Example from docs: https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller/blob/master/packages/demo/src/components/DynamicScrollerDemo.vue